# Pythonic way of diffing two arrays

Tags: python

I call two API endpoints and receive the following responses:

```
applications = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'app1'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'app2'}]
types = [{'id': '3', 'name': 'app1'}, {'id': '4', 'name': 'app1'}]
```

I'm looking for the following output:

```
app1 has 2 types.
app2 has 0 types.
```

I could achieve this with nested for loops, but what's the most Pythonic way of achieving this?

Comment: What's the format of the response? JSON?

Comment: Please provide a minimal code and example. I don't understand how you get your expected output.

Comment: Why has app2 0 types? How is this being calculated?

Comment: Your question is clear, but your title should could be phrased better - there are no arrays here, and no diffing.

Comment: _"I could achieve this with nested for loops"_. Please share the code you used to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

```
types = [app['name'] for app in types]
apps = {app['name']:types.count(app['name']) for app in applications}
```

The apps dictionary will give you an apps count in types.
Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
counts = pd.DataFrame(types).groupby('name').count()
application_names = {x['name'] for x in applications}
{name: counts['id'].get(name, 0) for name in application_names}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` to map the app names to type counts efficiently:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(type['name'] for type in types)
for app in applications:
    print(f'{app["name"]} has {counts[app["name"]]} types.')
```

This outputs:

```
app1 has 2 types.
app2 has 0 types.
```